# Féminin de « costaud » ?

Tags: usage, vocabulaire, genre

J'ai souvent entendu le mot

> costaud

mais jamais son féminin

> costaude.

Est-ce que la version féminine existe ? Est-elle effectivement employée ?

Answer (score 7):

Tout à fait, costaude existe : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/costaude

En revanche, c'est assez peu utilisé, en France du moins, au profit de forte, musclée,  puissante, ou balèze selon le registre de langage.

Answer (score 5):

On peut dire `forte`, `musclée`, `charpentée` aussi !

Answer (score 5):

Au féminin, certains emploient « costaude » et d'autre « costaud » (voir l'[entrée du TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/costaud) mais elle me semble sous-estimer la fréquence de « costaud » comme forme utilisée au féminin).

Answer (score 0):

Costaude existe et se dit au féminin. Souvent avec un sens péjoratif. Quelqu'un qui voudrait simplement désigner une femme avec les mêmes qualités qu'un homme costaud parlerait plus volontiers d'une femme musclée. Une "femme costaude" renvoie à un imaginaire "butch", trapu, assez peu flatteur pour une femme. Il est donc rarement employé, sinon pour se moquer.